# grails 3 functional test plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

When I use grails 2, I use the [functional plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/functional-test) to create the function test and I use [Rest-client-builder](https://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) to send post and get request. The function test itself can start up the server.

However, When I upgrade to grails 3. the built in geb framework can help me create the function test. However, I don't know how i can send the post and get request. And the function test itself can not start up the server. I have to run-app first and then run the test. Does anyone know what should I do function post/get test via grails 3?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And the function test itself can not start up the server.

You haven't described the details of what you are doing so I don't know why it might not be working for you, but it certainly can be made to work.  You probably want to create integration tests and mark them with `@Integration`.  We have a lot of examples in the project at https://github.com/grails/grails3-functional-tests.  Look in https://github.com/grails/grails3-functional-tests/tree/master/app1/src/integration-test/groovy/functionaltests.  A simple example that should be easy to read is at https://github.com/grails/grails3-functional-tests/blob/master/app1/src/integration-test/groovy/functionaltests/HomeSpec.groovy.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Jeff. I want to find some plugin which can send out post and get request. Now I found :`compile org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:4.0.4.RELEASE"`.  It works via RestBuilder now. If you know other plugin which can sent request. I am glad that you can share here. Thanks very much for all your help